# Extend the Magento2 link_block widget

Tags: magento2, widget

I want to extend the Luma Theme Catalog Category Link widget to include the category image.

I have create my own version of the link_block.phtml file and it is working, but I am not sure how to get access to the Category Image?

When I add this code I get the following error and it is because the Widget/Link.php doesn't have a function to get the image but how do I add it?

This is added to link_block.phtml;

```
<?php
    $_helper    = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_category  = $block->getCurrentCategory();
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image"><img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" alt="' . $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" title="' . $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" class="image" /></div>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_imgHtml;
    }
?>
```

and then i get this error;

Fatal error: Call to a member **function getImageUrl()** on null in `/home/crabapp1/hire/app/design/frontend/CrabApple/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml on line 14`